# jquery AutoComplete save the searchstring typed in

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am a newbie at jquery. I have read up and tried a number of different events within the autocomplete method to do what I want without success.

Anyways I have an autocomplete function as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SearchContactWorker")
        .each(function () {
            var urlloc = "/Worker/FindWorkers";

            $(this).autocomplete({
                 source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: urlloc, type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                        data: { searchString: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                  return { label: item.name, value: item.name, id: item.id }
                            }))

                        }
                    })
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("[id$='ContactID']").val(ui.item.id);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Curently when a item is selected I save the ID in a hidden input called ContactID
Now if the user enters some text that does not return any results I want to save that text against a different hidden input type called ContactFullName .How do I do this??

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `change` event:

```
$(this).autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlloc, type: "POST", dataType: "json",
            data: { searchString: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                      return { label: item.name, value: item.name, id: item.id }
                }))

            }
        })
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item) {
            $("[id$='ContactID']").val(ui.item.id);
        } else {
            $("#ContactFullName").val(this.value);
        }
    }
});
```

- `ui.item` will be `null` if the user did not select an item.
- Note that the `change`  event is fired when the field is blurred out of.

Comment: Thank you for your help.One problem with the change event it that it only triggers when the autocomplete box loses focus. Is there any other event that I can use?